# Displaying prices with / without tax based upon customer group

Tags: magento-1.8, customer-group

I currently have 3 groups, Group A which tax applies to and the other 2 (Group B & C) which tax doesn't apply.

I would like to know is it possible so that when not logged in or logged in as Group A the prices are displayed with the tax applied everywhere. However when logged in as Group B & C the prices are displayed without tax everywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem its not natively possible.

However looking at

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532650/magento-showing-prices-ex-inc-tax-vat-depending-on-customer-group

This provides a solution but ideally it would of been better to give the admin the choose in the backend rather than hardcoding it in

Comment: feel free to add the code from that answer here.

Comment: Code from related question

Cloned core file to app/code/local/Mage/Tax/Model/Config.php and updated the getPriceDisplayType function:

`public function getPriceDisplayType($store = null)
{   $customer = Mage::helper('customer')->getCustomer();
    if ($customer->getGroupId() > 1) {
        return self::DISPLAY_TYPE_BOTH;
    } else {
    return (int)Mage::getStoreConfig(self::CONFIG_XML_PATH_PRICE_DISPLAY_TYPE, $store);
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible out of the box but then class `Mage_Tax_Helper_Data` has all the functions to do with display prices with or without tax. For example `displayPriceIncludingTax` and `displayPriceExcludingTax`, though there are more.

What you could do is rewrite this helper and change these functions to match your need. Though tax display is a slippery slope so make sure you test this a lot :)